# Issue with sending XML to Web Api via http Post request

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, webapp2

I would like to send the following XML document to my Web Api 2 controller; however, the `[FromBody]` parameter is always null.

Here is the request XML body:

```html
<razorInbound server="PortfolioExposureServer" request="lookupRiskPointRecord">
  <caller>RazorClient</caller>
  <responseMode>xml</responseMode>
  <body>
    <conditions>
      <fromOffset>0</fromOffset>
      <top>100</top>
      <condition>
        <keyPath>
          <keyElement nodeOffset='1'>Currency</keyElement>
          <keyElement nodeOffset='2'>ID</keyElement>
        </keyPath>
        <lookupValue>USD</lookupValue>
      </condition>
    </conditions>
  </body>
</razorInbound>
```

Using Postman to send the request, is as follows :

```html
POST /api/razorXmlRequest HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Type: application/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6ca91ebf-31e0-77f2-6f81-cb9993b69b1a

<razorInbound server="PortfolioExposureServer" request="lookupRiskPointRecord">
  <caller>RazorClient</caller>
  <responseMode>xml</responseMode>
  <body>
    <conditions>
      <fromOffset>0</fromOffset>
      <top>100</top>
      <condition>
        <keyPath>
          <keyElement nodeOffset='1'>Currency</keyElement>
          <keyElement nodeOffset='2'>ID</keyElement>
        </keyPath>
        <lookupValue>USD</lookupValue>
      </condition>
    </conditions>
  </body>
</razorInbound>
```

And the Web Api 2 controller :

NOTE: The `param` parameter is always `null`

I believe I need a proper class definition to correctly map the XML request, but I'm not sure how to construct it.

```js
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using RazorServices;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace RazorWebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/razorXmlRequest")]
    public class RazorXmlRequestController : ApiController
    {
        public class RawXml {
            public string RazorXml { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]RawXml param )
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            // code omitted...
   
            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```

And by the way, we are currently getting around this issue by setting up a `StreamReader` object to pull from `this.Request.Content`; however in my unit test I need to send my xml as a parameter.

```js
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()   // [FromBody]RawXml param )
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), Encoding.UTF8);
            string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();

            if (xml == null || xml.Length < 4)
            {
                throw new RazorServicesException("Invalid XML");
            }
            RazorSession cred = RzWebApi.Cred;
            string reply = await RzWebApi.RazorSrv.xmlRequests.Request(cred, xml);
            resp.Content = new StringContent(reply, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
            return resp;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Final solution was to change the Post param type to `XElement`:

```
[Route("api/razorXmlRequest")]
public class RazorXmlRequestController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Raw Razor request XML 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Razor reply message as text</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]XElement xml)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        RazorSession cred = RzWebApi.Cred;
        string reply = await RzWebApi.RazorSrv.xmlRequests.Request(cred, xml);
        resp.Content = new StringContent(reply, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        return resp;
    }
}
```

This worked straight-away without even providing the `XmlFormatter` as the gentlemen had suggested above (@TusharJ, thank you anyway for your input).

Comment: I tried something similar but getting an error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128537/parameterless-constructor-exception-while-using-xelement .Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure Web API to use `XmlSerializer` in your `WebApiConfig.Register` as follows;

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: Turns out that I can change the Post method to `Post([FromBody]XElement param )` and the header's `Content-Type: application/xml`, and this will solve the problem. The `xml` content gets passed to the controller even without your suggestion above.