# How To Read data from XML Payload request in webapi using c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I need to Validate the Posted XML data from Postman or fiddler,

Can anyone please explain how to accept the XML data payload through web API post request to validate the data.

Thanks in Advance,
Srinivas.

Comment: pls add more details

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.008/cXML.dtd">

<cXML timestamp="2017-04-06T05:44:31-04:00" version="1.2.0025" payloadID="ddae93458f4-20b0-4f9d-91b8-7ca854f27568" xml:lang="en-US">
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="NetworkId">
<Identity>FakeIdentity</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="NetworkId">
<Identity>FakeIdentity1</Identity>
</Credential>
</To>                       this is our cxml file i need to get the  timestamp value and remaining which are like " " this  type of values...!

Comment: So many answers are already available. i.e. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424559/issue-with-sending-xml-to-web-api-via-http-post-request

Comment: Hi,actually we are working on api so need to send the cxml data to our post request through fiddler "the data is completely in cxml format not xml " so that in our api post request we will get the data and need to insert the cxml data in database..! we have all the fields in database that which cxml contains... we are not getting this please help me out!! thankyou