# .net core 2.0 web api httppost with xml input comes in as null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Trying to get a .net core 2.0 web api HttpPost method to work with xml input.

**Expected Result:** When the test endpoint is called from Postman, the input parameter (xmlMessage in the below code) should have the value being sent from the Postman HttpPost body.

**Actual Result:** input parameter is null.

In startup.cs of the web api project, we have the following code:

```
public class Startup
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddMvc()
      .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
   }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      app.UseMvc();
   }
}
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost, Route("test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] XMLMessage xmlMessage)
{
    return null; //not interested in the result for now
}
```

XMLMessage class:

```
[DataContract]
public class XMLMessage
{
    public XMLMessage()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

In Postman Headers:

```
Content-Type:application/xml
```

Http Post Body:

```
<XMLMessage>
  <MessageId>testId</MessageId>
</XMLMessage>
```

Appreciate any help that could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424559/issue-with-sending-xml-to-web-api-via-http-post-request

Comment: Thanks for the link @RuiJarimba. using XElement as the parameter type gets the xml value into the input parameter xmlMessage. However, I'm interested in getting the xml value directly deserialized to my XMLMessage class object.

Comment: Just to help troubleshoot your `XMLMessage` class, try using the `XElement` to receive the XML and then write code [along the lines of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010191/using-datacontractserializer-to-serialize-but-cant-deserialize-back?answertab=votes#tab-top) to ensure you've configured the `DataContract` annotation correctly. It may be that Web API isn't able to match the class type to the incoming XML.

Comment: @SixtoSaez, that did the trick. I called the Deserialize method and got the error: `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebApi.Controllers"
SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 13. Expecting element XMLMessage from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebApi.Controllers.. 
Encountered Element with name XMLMessage, namespace .` Once I added the namespace like: `<XMLMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWebApi.Controllers">`, it started working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matt.G could you please post your full Startup.cs code?

Comment: @RuiJarimba, I have edited the post to include the full Startup.cs code (working version). Please note that I removed the config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter());, as it was working without that

Answer (score 4):

You should be using XmlRoot/XmlElement instead of the DataContract/DataElement annotations types. Below is what should be changed in order to make it work.

On Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
    // Add remaining settings
}
```

XMLMessage class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XMLMessage")]
public class TestClass
{
    //XmlElement not mandatory, since property names are the same
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MessageId")]
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

The other pieces look good (Controller and header).

Michał Białecki created a very nice post about the topic. Please refer to it for more a more detailed implementation:
[Accept XML request in ASP.Net MVC Controller](http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/25/accept-xml-request-in-asp-net-mvc-controller/)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work. The only thing I had to change was the method `Startup.ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); 
}
```

Comment: Rui Jarumba, tried this now, getting error: `Parse: Error parsing request: Root element is missing.`

Comment: Seriously? I think my code and my request (using Postman) are exactly the same as yours. Let me double-check if there are any differences. Is the `Content-Type` the only header you added?

Comment: @Matt.G I can't find any differences, other than the ConfigureServices method. Controller method, XMLMessage data contract and the Postman request seems to be exactly like yours

Comment: @Matt.G Which versions of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` nuget packages are you using? mine are v2.0.9 and v2.0.0

Comment: v2.0.8 and v2.0.0. tried upgrading to v.2.0.9, still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Startup.cs

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            }).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace test.Controllers
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody]TestClass test)
        {
            return Ok("OK");
        }

    }

}
```

Program.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

```
namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

test.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this earlier, with no success.

Comment: could you post your Startup.cs?

Comment: I have already added the relevant code from startup.cs in my post. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: you added `new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter()` in the InputFormatters, and try `new XmlSerializerInputFormatter()`

Comment: I reproduced your issue when changing `XmlSerializerInputFormatter ` to `XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter()`

Comment: Jianping Liu, I tried this: getting error: `Parse: Error parsing request: Root element is missing.`

Comment: It's strange, I will post my code and you can try it