# Parameterless constructor exception while using XElement

Tags: c#, constructor, xelement

I am writing a POST API where the code will receive an XML object as the payload to check for certain data and then pass it on to the third-party API.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public string SubscriptionSettings([FromBody] XElement request)
{
  if (request != null && request.HasAttributes)
  {
   //Logic
  }
  return "some value";
}
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving the error **No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**
I do understand that I should create a parameterless constructor for **XElement**.

But I don't think that is the right way in this scenario.

Sample request payload:

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <Select>
      <LIST>AAA</LIST>
            <ID>data</ID>
    </Select>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Please suggest.

**Edit 1**:
Stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +271

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +345
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +750
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +466
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +679
```

Header in request:

```
authorization:Bearer aQwkhBb6XKEb5ZDm8-Gs7HsnvE08jgiY9rSocEm8F0S4S1
Content-Type:text/xml
```

I also tried with the following header:

```
authorization:Bearer aQwkhBb6XKEb5ZDm8-Gs7HsnvE08jgiY9rSocEm8F0S4S1
    Content-Type:text/json
```

But the response is the same.

Comment: 1) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, traceback, message and inner exception(s) if any?  2) Are you sure your XML is not getting processed as JSON?

Comment: @dbc: I have updated the details in the question itself.